# UITableview not responding to events

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

[image]

I am building a "Utility Application" using Xcode and above is a screenshot of the view that can be seen on flipping over from the main view controller. The `UITableView` inside this view has the delegate and source set to the `UIViewController` for the containing View, the table data gets populated appropriately (imply the `uiviewcontroller` behaves correctly as the data source) however the table does not respond to any of the events i.e. the delegate methods do not get called for the table. I am not even able to select any of the rows for the table.

Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Yes, userInteractionEnabled is set to YES. Also here is the code to generate the cell

```
 -(UITableViewCell*)populateFeatureCell:(UITableView*)tableView row:(NSUInteger)row {
```

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FeatureCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

SKProduct *product = [STLNavigatorIAPHelper productAtIndex:row];
if (product != nil) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [product localizedTitle];
    UIButton *buyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    buyButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 72, 37);
    [buyButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"BUY", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buyButton.tag = row;
    [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
     cell.accessoryView = buyButton;
}

[cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: is `userInteractionEnabled` set to YES on the table view?

Comment: Yes, userInteractionEnabled is set to YES. Also here is the code to generate the cell

Comment: Have you verified that the delegate of the UITableView is not 'nil'? (i.e. add a conditional print statement in the method you've posted)